# Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue using Angular %http service

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I'm getting the following Angular $http error below :

XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://localhost:14985/api/init?space=rz64698&environment=rz64698&clConfig=C:\Rz\rz64698\master\bin\cl_config.xml`. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

This separate .Net API project is running in IIS on port 14985. My ASP.NET MVC/Angular project is running on localhost port 49479. So I need to learn out how to deal with cross-origin calls.

I'd like to know specifically how to include the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in my request. I will continue to investigate in the meantime, and will post my findings asap.

Here is the function in my datacontext.js :

```
 function initRz() {
        domain = "localhost:"
        port = "14985";
        controllerpath = "/api/init";
        space = "rz64698";
        env = "rz64698";
        clconfig = "C:\\Rz\\rz64698\\master\\bin\\cl_config.xml";
        var url = "http://" + domain + port + controllerpath + "?space=" + space + "&environment=" + env + "&clConfig=" + clconfig;
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var retval = [];
        $http.defaults.headers.get = { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': true };
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            encoding: 'JSONP',
             headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'true' // THIS ALSO WORKS
            },                 
            withCredentials: true,
            url: url
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            retval = data;
            deferred.resolve(retval);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http Search for "withCredentials". Also, the server that you are requesting the resource from must have CORS configured to allow requests from that origin (your localhost in this case). If you have control over this server hosting the API, then for development purposes you could configure it to allow any site to request resources from it (by using `*` in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header.) Here's a page about CORS that might be useful: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: @pje - thx for the response. I've added added $http.defaults and withCredentials: true to my original $http() call above. Does this look correct ? I've also asked the API developer to include 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' in his response.

Comment: Yeah, that should include the correct header when requesting CORS from that API. Now it's a matter of whether or not that API developer will be willing to configure their server to allow any CORS request. See also, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#section_5 for more info on CORS.

Comment: @pje - indeed it works. I can verify the Access-Control-Request-Headers: header attribute in fidder. I also included the headers: section in my original post to show folks that this will work as well. I'm now waiting on the other developer to modify his side.